# Point domain A to single page of Joomla site with different domain B, but keep Domain A as url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, joomla, dns

I've looked at a couple different questions on here that looked like they might answer my issue, (like: [Domain to point to a single page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371143/domain-to-point-to-a-single-page)) but not quite.  They've gotten me close, but this is still not working for me, and I think the issue is likely how Joomla creates the SEF urls.

I have a Joomla site "mainsite.com" (for example) and I have a new domain "quiz.com" (for example).  I would like to have a masked redirect where new domain quiz.com points to a Joomla page I have off the mainsite - mainsite.com/quiz, yet keep quiz.com as the address.  So quiz.com = mainsite.com/quiz, but the domain quiz.com stays in the url bar.

So in CPanel, I added the new site quiz.com as an addon domain.  It also created a directory for it under public_html/quiz.com 
In that directory, I have this in the .htacess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^quiz\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.quiz\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/mainsite\.com\/quiz\/" [R=301,L]
```

What is happening is when I bring up quiz.com, it actually brings up quiz.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi ??  There isn't even a cgi-sys bin in that folder?  There is only a .htaccess file?  Has anyone seen this or can offer any help?  Anything would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks so much!

Comment: So Joomla is mainsite.com but quiz.com is some other application? Did you try doing it as a wrapper?  Do you totally want to lose the template when quiz displays?

Comment: quiz.com is an empty domain right now, I only want to use it as a masked domain for mainsite.com/quiz 
No, I don't want to lose the template.

Comment: also, can't use Wrapper/iFrame because client has a lot of Google Analytics they want to grab from it.

Comment: I would really prefer to do it in the .htaccess

Comment: So, does anyone have any suggestions on how to mask a single Joomla page with a separate domain name in .htaccess?  Both domains reside on the same server. I've been trying many different things and nothing seems to be giving me the masking result I need.  :-(  Any help at all is very greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: So what you want is to have one specific Joomla page have a different domain right? But the content itself is Joomla content and will display exactly as it would normally in Joomla? Is this exactly one page? Which site has the analytics that you want?  Will the user click out from this page back to the normal pages i.e. if you have relative links on that page back to the main site they will be broken?

Comment: Actually 4 pages:
1) quiz_login
2) quiz-home
3) QuizForm
4) SubmitInfo

All 4 pages are "hidden" from the main site - no links to them exist. 
No relative links to worry about, the menu and any other links from the main site have been stripped out, the page is using an empty template with no menu.
The user won't be linking to anywhere else other than those 4 pages
As for analytics - we need to grab the stats from each distinct page, and I suppose the domain name doesn't matter, as long as we can match it up with the page name.  So, now that I think of it, maybe a wrapper CAN actually work?

Comment: Actually, I'm sorry, no, doing an iFrame won't work as I just remembered the client had us add some directives to the .htaccess file a while back that to prevent Frame Hijacking from other domains.  Ugh.  This is just getting messier.

Comment: But they are Joomla pages not a separate application?

Comment: correct. Joomla pages.  Not a separate application.  I basically wanted just a few Joomla pages from one site to be part of a different domain. I'm not even sure that's possible.  BUt thank you for all your help.